# visual c++ 2010 can't add resource file

Tags: c++, resources

i want to add to my project a resource file but vs2010 won't let me.
what do i do?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the resources folder?

Comment: yes, when i try to add a new item it only gives me header & cpp files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Express Edition, then you can't compile resources (may be it is a reason, why you can't add them too).

Comment: I believe the express edition includes the resource compiler, but not editor, and therefore these things aren't available in the IDE.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Has no resource editor, but has compiler. So, author can use 3rd party resource editor and add compiled .res file to his project.

Comment: I used the ResEditor found on this page:  http://www.thefreecountry.com/programming/resourceeditors.shtml. Once I had the rc file created, I was able to see my image in my VS 2010 Express project.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a Win32 Application, do **not** select "Empty project", and it will create some resource files for you, you can add your own resource in it.(ProjectName.rc->View Code...then edit)