# Adding Resources in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources, bitmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [visual c++ 2010 can't add resource file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488794/visual-c-2010-cant-add-resource-file)

To add bitmap I should add it as a resource (that's what I read in some tutorial). So when I right-click on a project name in Visual C++, and then find 'Add' submenu, I find that adding resource button is inactive (grey). How can I add bitmap then? Or how do I make adding resources work?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488794/visual-c-2010-cant-add-resource-file

Comment: thanks for the link. That means i need to fina a 3rd party resource editor. Can You offer any?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.suite101.com/content/vc-express-external-res-editor-a21264) off of Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual C++ Express editions don't have a resource editor. That is one of its limitations.

However, maybe this will help: http://www.suite101.com/content/vc-express-external-res-editor-a21264.